# aws-sdk-go getting NoCredentialProviders when using kube2iam

Tags: aws-sdk-go

We are using [kube2iam](https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam) to pass ec2 roles inside containers. Occasionally we get:

```
Error: Failed to list store contents: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

but then if we restart the container - credentials are picked up.

Seems like we are hitting an issue when [kube2iam takes time](https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam/issues/31) to pass the credentials.

I did find [this commit](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/commit/7d9ac5f2079172b9725513796718eaad96218f3b) that makes the timeout even shorter.

So question is:
Is there a way to introduce delayed retries in aws-sdk-go similar to `AWS_METADATA_SERVICE_TIMEOUT`/`AWS_METADATA_SERVICE_NUM_ATTEMPTS`?

Answer (score 2):

The Go AWS SDK does not have a direct notion of `AWS_METADATA_SERVICE_TIMEOUT/AWS_METADATA_SERVICE_NUM_ATTEMPTS`, but it does have a similar concept.

By default, when a `EC2Metadata` type is created (which is used by the default credentials chain), [a timeout override of 1 second is set](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/5d8a3d6c71e822edf1e5b7037989283ddd7b1c8e/aws/ec2metadata/service.go#L83) on the `http.Client`. If your `kube2iam` does not respond within that time, the credential call will fail.

You can disable this behavior using the `EC2MetadataDisableTimeoutOverride` option on your `aws.Config` when creating the `session.Session`. When doing this, the timeout will match the behavior of `http.DefaultClient`.

Example:

```
cfg := aws.NewConfig().
    WithEC2MetadataDisableTimeoutOverride(true).
    WithCredentialsChainVerboseErrors(true)

sess, _ := session.NewSession(cfg)

db := dynamodb.New(sess) // etc.
```